# Return to South Africa passport query

Tags: passports, paperwork, south-africa

Family of 3 looking to return to SA.  I need to renew my SA passport and ID.  My husband needs to apply for passport but does have ID.  My daughter (13) needs to apply for all documents.  Is it quicker and is it legal to travel to SA on our British passports then apply for everything there?  Will it take less than 90 days to get everything done?  It seems very long winded to do everything from the UK. We have been living in the UK for 25 years so we are unsure of how things work there but I don’t think you can apply online for passports like you can in UK.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you UK or SA citizens?

Comment: If the process for getting a ZA passport in the UK is anything like it is in the USA, then yes it is long-winded (and nothing like the easy online process of getting a UK passport in the USA).

Comment: It shouldn't matter how long it takes as long as you can prove your South African nationality by other means.  You can't be deported, and if there is a penalty for a dual national using a foreign passport at immigration control, you'll already have had to deal with that.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  To answer the first question - my husband and I were born in the UK but our families emigrated to SA when we were young.  I hold both UK and SA passports.  My husband has never had a SA passport but has an ID book.  My daughter was born in the UK and holds only a British passport.  I am hoping we can register her birth and apply for her SA passport when we arrive in SA.  The same goes for my husband and I.  Thanks for the advice - if anyone sees this and can offer any further advice that would be great.  Thank you.